# Tictactoe crashes of value is greater or equal to 9

Tags: java

Editing my sister's tic-tac-toe code and she (also I) hit a snag. If Player one was to type a number greater than 9 or type a number that at was already used it will crash. Is there and recommended solution to problem.

```
printGameBoard(gameBoard);

        //User input requests
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter your placement (1-9):");
            int playerPos = scan.nextInt();
            while(playerPositions.contains(playerPos) || cpuPositions.contains(playerPositions) || cpuPositions.contains(playerPos)){
                System.out.println("Position taken! Enter another position:");
                playerPos = scan.nextInt();
                //Prevent user from printing on top of CPU
                while(playerPositions.contains(playerPos) || cpuPositions.contains(playerPos)){
                    System.out.println("Position taken! Enter another position:");
                    playerPos= scan.nextInt();
                }
            }

            placePiece(gameBoard, playerPos, "player");

            String result = checkWinner();
            if(result.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(result);
                break;            
            }
            //CPU random positions (this what you are looking for)
            Random rand = new Random();
            int cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
            while(playerPositions.contains(cpuPos) || cpuPositions.contains(cpuPos)){
                cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }

            placePiece(gameBoard, cpuPos, "cpu");

            printGameBoard(gameBoard);

            result = checkWinner();
            if(result.length() > 0){
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void placePiece(char[][] gameBoard, int pos, String user){

        char symbol = ' ';

        if(user.equals("player")){
            symbol = 'X';
            playerPositions.add(pos);
        } else if(user.equals("cpu")){
            symbol = 'O';
            cpuPositions.add(pos);
        }

        switch(pos){
            case 1:
                gameBoard[0][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 2:
                gameBoard[0][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 3:
                gameBoard[0][4] = symbol;
                break;
            case 4:
                gameBoard[2][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 5:
                gameBoard[2][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 6:
                gameBoard[2][4] = symbol;
                break;
            case 7:
                gameBoard[4][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 8:
                gameBoard[4][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 9:
                gameBoard[4][4] = symbol;
                break;                          
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static String checkWinner(){        
        // (This define what a winng move looks like) 
        List topRow = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List midRow = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
        List botRow = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
        List leftCol = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7);
        List midCol = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8);
        List rightCol = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9);
        List cross1 = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9);
        List cross2 = Arrays.asList(7, 5, 3);

        List<List> winning = new ArrayList<List>();
        winning.add(topRow);
        winning.add(midRow);
        winning.add(botRow);
        winning.add(leftCol);
        winning.add(midCol);
        winning.add(rightCol);
        winning.add(cross1);
        winning.add(cross2);

        for(List l : winning){
            if(playerPositions.containsAll(l)){
                return "Congraduations you won!";
            } else if(cpuPositions.containsAll(l)){
                return "CPU wins! Sorry!";
            } else if(playerPositions.size() + cpuPositions.size() == 9){
                return "We are tied!";
            }
        }

        return "";       
    }

    public static void printGameBoard (char [][] gameBoard){ 
        for(char[] row : gameBoard) {
            for(char c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);              
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}


PLAYGAME CODE

import java.util.*;

public class PlayGame
{
    private int incrementer;
    private char location[]=new char[10];
    private char gamer;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String ch;
        PlayGame Toe=new PlayGame();
        do{
            Toe.beginBoard();
            Toe.startplay();
            System.out.println ("Would you like to play again (Enter 'Y')? ");
            Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
            ch=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("ch value is "+ch);
        }while (ch.equals("Y"));

    }
    public void beginBoard()
    {

        char locationdef[] = {'0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        int i;
        incrementer = 0;
        gamer = 'X';
        for (i=1; i<10; i++) location[i]=locationdef[i];
        presentBoard();

    }
    public String presentBoard()
    {
        System.out.println( "\n\n" );
        System.out.println( "\n\n" );
        System.out.println( "\n\n\t\t" + location [1] + " | " +location [2]+ " | " +location [3]);
        System.out.println( " \t\t | | " );
        System.out.println( " \t\t ___|____|___ " );
        System.out.println( "\n\n\t\t" +location [4]+ " | " +location [5]+ " | " +location [6]);
        System.out.println( " \t\t | | " );
        System.out.println( " \t\t ___|____|___ " );
        System.out.println( "\n\n\t\t" +location [7]+ " | " +location [8]+ " | " +location [9]);
        System.out.println( " \t\t | | " );
        System.out.println( " \t\t | | " );
        System.out.println( "\n\n" );
        return "presentBoard";
    }

    public void startplay()
    {
        int center;
        char blank = ' ';

        System.out.println( "gamer " + locategamer() +" will go first and be the letter 'X'" );

        do {
            presentBoard();

            System.out.println( "\n\n gamer " + locategamer() +" choose a location." );

            boolean currentlocation = true;
            while (currentlocation) {

                Scanner in =new Scanner (System.in);
                center=in.nextInt();
                currentlocation = checklocation(center);
                if(currentlocation==false)
                    location[center]=locategamer();
            }

            System.out.println( "Excellent move" );

            presentBoard();

            latergamer();
        }while ( getWinner() == blank );

    }

    public char getWinner()
    {
        char Winner = ' ';

        if (location[1] == 'X' && location[2] == 'X' && location[3] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[4] == 'X' && location[5] == 'X' && location[6] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[7] == 'X' && location[8] == 'X' && location[9] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[1] == 'X' && location[4] == 'X' && location[7] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[2] == 'X' && location[5] == 'X' && location[8] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[3] == 'X' && location[6] == 'X' && location[9] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[1] == 'X' && location[5] == 'X' && location[9] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (location[3] == 'X' && location[5] == 'X' && location[7] == 'X') Winner = 'X';
        if (Winner == 'X' )
        {System.out.println("gamer1 wins the game." );
            return Winner;
        }

        if (location[1] == 'O' && location[2] == 'O' && location[3] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[4] == 'O' && location[5] == 'O' && location[6] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[7] == 'O' && location[8] == 'O' && location[9] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[1] == 'O' && location[4] == 'O' && location[7] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[2] == 'O' && location[5] == 'O' && location[8] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[3] == 'O' && location[6] == 'O' && location[9] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[1] == 'O' && location[5] == 'O' && location[9] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (location[3] == 'O' && location[5] == 'O' && location[7] == 'O') Winner = 'O';
        if (Winner == 'O' )
        {
            System.out.println( "gamer2 wins the game." );
            return Winner; }

        for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(location[i]=='X' || location[i]=='O')
            {
                if(i==9)
                {
                    char Draw='D';
                    System.out.println(" Game is draw ");
                    return Draw;
                }
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;

        }

        return Winner;
    }

    public boolean checklocation(int center)
    {

        if (location[center] == 'X' || location[center] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println("That location is already occupied please choose another location");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }


    }


    public void latergamer()
    {
        if (gamer == 'X')
            gamer = 'O';
        else gamer = 'X';

    }

    public String locatename()
    {
        return " Game Tic Tac Toe" ;
    }

    public char locategamer()
    {
        return gamer;
    }

}
```

i found code to fix redundant input, but not the crash when input is higher than 9

Comment: Have you tried running it on a debugger? you might be having an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to check the input first and reject it if it is an invalid location (less than 1 or greater than 9).

In the class `PlayGame` that would mean to change the `checklocation()` method:

```
    public boolean checklocation(int center)
    {
        if (center < 1 || 9 < center)
        {
            System.out.println("That location is not valid please choose another location");
            return true;
        }
        else if (location[center] == 'X' || location[center] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println("That location is already occupied please choose another location");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```